# how to change user id to their name in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i need help. i have a table that i need to view the data of the user that already doing report. when the technician update the form, user can know who is the responsible person for their report. upon update the technician will send the id to the database but the problem is the user will see the id when they check the report. i need to change the id to the technician name.

```html
<tr bgcolor="#00aeef">
        <td>Tarikh</td>
        <td>Staff ID</td>
        <td>Kerosakan</td>
        <td>Nyatakan</td>
        <td>Maklumat Kerosakan</td>
        <td>Lokasi Kerosakan</td>
        <td>Nama Pegawai</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Catatan</td>
      </tr>
     <?php include('../dbcon.php');

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$username_view=$_SESSION['username_view'];

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aduan_form where staff_id='$username' ORDER BY tarikh DESC") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php while ($row_view = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){ ?>
<?php if ($totalRows_view > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
  <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['tarikh']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['staff_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['kerosakan']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['nyatakan']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['m_kerosakan']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['tempat_rosak']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['nama_pegawai']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['status']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_view['catatan']; ?></td>
      <?php } while ($row_view = mysql_fetch_assoc($view)); ?></tr>
    </table>
```

here is my current code.

i do try to put some code that will allow the id to change to the name but it view the same name and it is even in the table that is still not been update.

```html
<?php include('../dbcon.php');

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$username_view=$_SESSION['username_view'];

$qry1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login,aduan_form where aduan_form.nama_pegawai=login.username ORDER BY aduan_form.tarikh DESC") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php while ($row_view1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry1)){ ?>
```

how should i do to make it right? i need the table to view the right technician name based on the right id and also display the name only in the table that already been update.

Comment: what table and column holds username you need?

Comment: the table that hold the username are the login table while the table that hold the id is the aduan_form table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your database schema right. So you can query like:

```
$qry1=mysql_query("
     SELECT aduan_form.*, login.username 
     FROM aduan_form 
     LEFT JOIN login
     ON login.id = aduan_form.staff_id
     WHERE aduan_form.nama_pegawai=login.username 
     ORDER BY aduan_form.tarikh DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

and change your html output to something like:

```
  ...
  <td><?php echo $row_view['tarikh']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_view['username']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_view['kerosakan']; ?></td>
  ...
```

Comment: it work, thank you but it is only view the data that is only already been update. how can i change the code to make it view all the data for the specific user even it is not being update?